# How to retrieve the matched lines from the BinaryDescriptorMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

How to get the matched lines after using the BinaryDescriptor with the match function on OpenCV?

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/line_descriptor/doc/tutorial.html

I am trying to run this code about line matching and I want to get the properties of the extracted lines and which lines is matched to what

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean information about the *KeyLine* type, the possibilities are mentioned in the OpenCV documentation. You can find that [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dd7/structcv_1_1line__descriptor_1_1KeyLine.html)

Additionally, for matches, the type *DMatch* also has functions which you can use to find the index of the matches (from one descriptor to the other), and the distance. You can find the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/de0/classcv_1_1DMatch.html). Hope it helps!